# What good is a Paladin's Divine Sense against invisibility?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, paladin, vision-and-light, invisibility

From the PHB:

> The presence of strong evil registers on your senses like
>   a noxious odor, and powerful good rings like heavenly
>   music in your ears. As an action, you can open your
>   awareness to detect such forces. Until the end of your
>   next turn, you know the location of any celestial, fiend,
>   or undead within 60 feet of you that is not behind total
>   cover.

What happens if such an enemy is invisible, though?
I know where it is but can't see it, so I still have disadvantage hitting it, right.
But if so, what's the advantage of sensing them in the first place?
Or does divine sense actually allow my Paladin to hit it like it was visible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, Divine Sense won't allow you to hit it as if it was visible. Invisibility says that:

> Attack rolls against the creature have disadvantage,
>   and the creature’s attack rolls have advantage.

and Divine Sense does nothing to change that. So what's the advantage of sensing them? Well, the advantage ***is*** that you sense them. If you use Divine Sense and discover that you're surrounded by undead and fiends, isn't that better than not knowing?

You could make the argument that if you knew to use Divine Sense, there wouldn't be any point to using it. This isn't really true, though: there's a big difference between knowing that there's *something* lurking nearby and knowing how many, where, and approximately what creatures are lurking nearby.

Finally, the most important benefit: knowing where it is means that **you know where it is**. This allows you to use spells like *Dispel Magic* to remove its invisibility, or just spells like *Fireball* to hurt it and invisibility be damned. For that matter, you said that you still have disadvantage hitting it, which is true, but at least you can *try* to hit it. (If you didn't have Divine Sense, you wouldn't even know where it is, you'd just have to swing your sword at a random square and hope. Unless you hit, you won't even know if you guessed right.)

Comment: Love that the most important benefit to knowing where something is, is knowing where something is.

Comment: Knowing roughly where they are, for example, allows your Bard to throw that sack of flower that he's been carrying and coat these invisible monsters with flour, or cast Faerie Fire, etc.

Comment: Do I not know that my hit something invisible? Conservation of momentum, Newton's third law and all that jazz. As a side question, when does the blood become visible?

Comment: @JanDborak Yes, but if you miss you won't know if you were even aiming at the right square

Comment: @JanDvorak As for the blood, remember that hit points are an abstraction and don't necessarily represent physical damage to the body. It's up to the DM if a creature bleeds on any given hit .

Comment: @Miniman unless the cause of your miss is that they parried or blocked (e.g, heavy armour or shields). If they dodge you remain clueless.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff I suspect the OP had a misconception where he thought that "invisibility" was just a generic buff that made attacks against you miss more, because that's the only quantified effect in the rules -- trapped in video game logic. It's important to remind new players to frame it as a real situation.

Answer (score 6):

#### You can attack the invisible creature with disadvantage

PHB page 194 "Unseen Attackers and Targets" says that if you cannot see a target for whatever reason, you get disadvantage on your roll.  Divine Sense says nothing about being able to see a creature, only knowledge of its location.

"Unseen Attackers and Targets" elaborates that when attacking an unseen creature, you must guess which square your target is on, and that if you guess incorrectly, you automatically miss.  Because you know what square the creature is on, you can attack that square with disadvantage on your roll. You can also inform your allies of the creature's location, allowing them to attack that square with disadvantage as well.

Comment: "on each turn" may be a bit much because you cannot use your "Divine Sense" that many times in a day. The invisible create may not move, but it is rather unlikely if you ask me.